# c# copy selected listbox items into a string

Tags: c#, foreach, listbox

I'm having some issues with getting selected values from a listbox into a string.

The list box contains multiple values, let's call them A-Z. Basically, I want to copy the selected items into a string.

```
var listarray = new System.Collections.ArrayList(listboxName.SelectedItems);

string myval = "";

foreach (var arr in listarray)
{
    myval = dep.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(myval); // this shows all the selected values
}

string finalStr = "some text before the values" + myval;
Console.WriteLine(finalStr);
```

I want the string to display "some text before the values A, B, C, D...", but instead, it outputs "some text before the values A"

The last `Console.WriteLine` only shows one value as opposed to all the selected values. I've tried adding the `finalStr` inside the `foreach` loop, but this creates multiple instances of the `finalStr` instead of just one string with multiple array values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) to build concatenated string from items collection:

```
string finalStr = "Some text before the values " + 
           String.Join(", ", listboxName.SelectedItems.Cast<YourItemType>());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're always setting myval to current value of dep.ToString - you should concatenate it (I think you meant arr not dep):

```
myval += arr.ToString() + ", ";
```

The easiest way to deal with the commas is to create additional list and use String.Join:

```
var selected = new List<string>();
foreach (var arr in listboxName.SelectedItems)
{
    selected.Add(arr.ToString());    
}

string finalStr = "some text before the values" + String.Join(", ", selected);
```